# Getting All Questions from Stack Exchange API that are Accepted

Tags: filter, stackexchange-api

I am a bit new with stack exchange API. I want to query all questions that have been asked that has an accepted answer. I know the /questions query returns an "is_accepted" key for each question but I tried to put in the URL "&is_accepted=true" but it did not work.

The reason I want to do that is to optimize the number of questions I can extract from my daily quota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to use the Advanced Search API like this:

https://api.stackexchange.com//2.2/search/advanced?accepted=True&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow.